# Best practices for Fortran data structures with mixed types

Tags: data-structures, fortran

For a project I need a map-like data structure that can store values of mixed data types with `character` keys.  For example my data structure might contain:

```
"A" -> 1
"B" -> 2.0d0
"C" -> "three"
```

I'm aware that I could use an allocatable unlimited polymorphic variable for the value, and select type to extract it; however, I've never seriously used this technique in production code.

Is this the best approach for solving this type of problem in Fortran?  If so, what are some best practices for working with `class(*)`?

Are there alternative solutions, and if so, what advantages do they have?

Comment: Usually, you declare a unbounded polymorpic component that can store any type of data. But for retrieval, you will need a function specialized for your data-type stored (you'll need to know beforehand _what_ data-type your are fetching)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/libAtoms/QUIP/blob/public/src/libAtoms/Dictionary.f95), [this](https://github.com/zerothi/fdict) and [this](https://github.com/mapmeld/fortran-machine/blob/master/flibs-0.9/flibs/src/datastructures/dictionary.f90).

Comment: Just recently there was a series of questions covering numerous pitfalls in this area.

Comment: *Is this the best approach for solving this type of problem in ... ?*  No it's a lousy approach, in Fortran or almost any other programming language.  It enables the capture of data so flexibly it's floppy, at the cost of leaving the processing to figure out what to do with whatever might turn up at the right side of an `->`. Far better to design data structures with, well, a bit more structure. Absent a good hard stare at all your requirements this is just a poorly-informed opinion.  As framed I'm not sure your question will get a much better response though.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, to be honest `class(*)` really annoys me for exactly the reason you mentioned -- using it is basically throwing away the advantages of static type checking.  So the real question I'm asking is: "if the stated interface is set in stone, what's the best implementation?"

Comment: A separate and highly valid question is: "Should the stated requirements be set in stone, or should they be modified to allow for a better implementation?"

Comment: You don't tell us nearly enough about your requirements for better 'answers' than what I've already shared, and I don't present that as much of an answer at all.  And make up your mind, are your requirements set in stone or not ?!  You can already guess my answer to the question *Should the stated requirements be set in stone ?* :-)

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues, thanks for the links, I'll take a look at what they're doing